# ANSI view get differed from notepad and notepad++.why?

Tags: encoding, notepad++, iso-8859-1, notepad

I am writing some data as a xml file with ISO-8859 encoding.If I tried to open the file in notepad++.I can able to see the 'Â' character which is already present in the file.But if I tried to open the file in notepad the character 'Â' gets removed.Though I am very new to Encoding,I don't know why.Please suggest some reason for this.

This file is also get opened in browser with the 'Â' character.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Windows notepad is a very basic editor, and has quite a number of limitations, one of which is the support it has for different encoding formats other than ANSI, Unicode and UTF-8. When editing files in other formats, it can give unreliable/unexpected results.

If you are handling files in different encoding formats, you are better off avoiding notepad altogether and using an editor (such as Notepad++) which has better support for multiple encoding formats.

For more information on how Windows notepad "guesses" at the correct format to use (with varying levels of success) [see here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/04/17/2158334.aspx)

Bear in mind that other editors often use similar techniques to "guess" the format of a file, so it is often a good idea to check/set the encoding for a file manually (where possible) for less common encoding formats to ensure you get the correct results every time.